# React Native clear getInitialURL after use

Tags: react-native

I am using `Linking` to handle SSO for my app. But the problem is that if the app is redirected once, `Linking.getInitialURL()` is called every time, even when the app is not redirected from other app.

I am calling the function in my root container like this

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.isMounted = true;
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.onRedirection);
    let initialURL = await Linking.getInitialURL();
    if (initialURL) {
      this.onRedirection({url: initialURL});
    }
  }
```

Comment: try to reproduce on a release build. I have the same issue in debug mode

Comment: Hi @VasylNahuliak I have tried this on release build and got same results.